KubeOps, XUnit: Call is ambiguous between ControllerRegistrations.RegisterControllers and ControllerRegistrations.RegisterControllers
I have a project which uses KubeOps for using KubernetesClient. Also i have a Xunit test project written in C#. In the test project, when i'm referencing the actual project getting the below error.

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ControllerRegistrations.RegisterControllers(KubeOps.Abstractions.Builder.IOperatorBuilder)' and 'ControllerRegistrations.RegisterControllers(KubeOps.Abstractions.Builder.IOperatorBuilder)'

How do I resolve this error?

You need an additional attribute in your actual project, where KuboOps is referenced.
<PackageReference Include="KubeOps.Generator" Version="8.0.1" PrivateAssets="all"/>

By that you will prevent your testing project from generating KubOps controller related code.
